# "Could not resolve it.archive.ubuntu.com"

Tags: networking, apt, 18.04, updates, dns

After a broken install (GParted) on my 18.04 LTS I've first tried

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

and

`sudo apt-get update`

In both cases, I got an error message saying that

`Impossibile risolvere "it.archive.ubuntu.com"` (*the italian version for Could not resolve "us.archive.ubuntu.com" in the general case*).

I've added to both /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/resolv.conf new DNS destinations, but nothing has changed. I've tried to ping 8.8.8.8 (all right) and it.archive.ubuntu.com (no result), so I've tried to navigate it.archive.ubuntu.com - the site seems down (I found just a cached version).

My question is, is there something I could do on my system, or I have to conclude that it.archive.ubuntu.com is simply unreachable?

I'm a real newbie on Linux, so I hope you'll be patient!

Comment: If this just started then wait a bit and try again later!

Comment: It's back. Try again.